# How to add class to only selected div based on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class to **mainmenu** div, but for some reason it add class to both the div, the div has same class, i only wanted to add class to selected div.

```
<div class="main-column">
    <div id="col1">
        <div class="hidden">hidden text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="class">
        <div class="menubox">
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menubox">
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="class">
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <div class="menubox">
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <div class="menubox">
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JQUERY code.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menubox .toggleClass').hover(function() {
      // fade in the div in this object.
      $(this).closest('.main-column').find('.class .mainmenu').toggleClass('class_name');
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) How many `main-coloumn` classes/div can there be in your page? (2) There are 2 `mainmenu` divs in `col3`. How do u decide which `mainmenu` to add class to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like:

```
    (function($) {
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.menubox .toggleClass').hover(function () {
                var mine. = $(this).closest('.mainmenu');
                $(this).closest('.main-column').find('.mainmenu').not( mine ).removeClass('class_name');
                mine.addClass('class_name');
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: thank for the answer, i only want to add class when we hover over col2 div .menubox .toggleClass, after hovering it should add class to column 3 .mainmenu class

Comment: @WaleedAfridi i think you should clarify that properly in your question. Your question is not very clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @SangSuantak thank you so much, we are very close to the solution, i recorded a small video to explain the issue, i hope this will clear my request. Here's the [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6fp95ljg5ovpvs/help.mov?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo:** https://dojo.telerik.com/IJoBeCeT/2

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menubox .toggleClass').hover(function() {
      // fade in the div in this object.
      $(this).parents('.mainmenu').toggleClass('class_name');
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.class_name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-column">
    <div id="col1">
        <div class="hidden">hidden text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="class">
        <div class="menubox">
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menubox">
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="class">
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <div class="menubox">
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <div class="menubox">
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
                <a class="toggleClass">toggleClass</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, we are very close to the solution, i recorded a small video to explain the issue, i hope this will clear my request. Here's the [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6fp95ljg5ovpvs/help.mov?dl=0)